# Using ng-annotate without Grant or Gulp

Tags: angularjs, minimize, ng-annotate

How to use `ng-annotate` module, when I have Gradle Build Tool and no Grant or Gulp in project? I need minimize my code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find alternative for building system that you use.

You can find some instructions here -  [Ng-annotate pipeline](https://github.com/craigburke/angular-annotate-asset-pipeline).

Answer (score 1):

There are some solutions that can let you call `node` scripts from your groovy code :

[Calling node from Gradle](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin)

[Invoking Grunt tasks from Gradle](https://github.com/srs/gradle-grunt-plugin)